# Can a Vue component behave like wordpress shortcode attributes

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Can a Vue component behave like wordpress shortcode attributes? For example in `[wp-shortcode post_type="post"]`, I can define the post type in the shortcode and the data will be fetched accordingly.

Can something similar be done in Vue? For example `<grid-one type="posts" />` or `<grid-one type="videos" />`. The type in the grid-one tag will change the `request.type` in the data.

GridOne.vue

```
<template>
  <main class="site-content">
    <div class="container">
      <section v-if="posts.length" class="articles-list">
        <post-item
          v-for="post in posts"
          :key="post.id"
          :post="post"
        />
        <pagination
          v-if="totalPages > 1"
          :total="totalPages"
          :current="page"
        />
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import PostItem from '@/components/template-parts/PostItem'
import Pagination from '@/components/template-parts/Pagination'

export default {
  name: 'GridOne',
  components: {
    PostItem,
    Pagination
  },
  props: {
    page: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      request: {
        type: 'posts',
        params: { 
          per_page: this.$store.state.site.posts_per_page,
          page: this.page
        }, 
        showLoading: true 
      },
      totalPages: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    posts() {
      return this.$store.getters.requestedItems(this.request)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      return this.$store.dispatch('getItems', this.request)
    },
    setTotalPages() {
      this.totalPages = this.$store.getters.totalPages(this.request)
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getPosts().then(() => this.setTotalPages())
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible and the two concepts are pretty much one and the same thing. If you think about it, `<div id="#app"></div>` itself ***is*** a "shortcode". And that's what the concept of components revolves around. You replace some piece of markup with a component tag and place it in a separate file, so it can be reused. Just like WP's shortcodes.

Comment: What alterations do I need to do in my code above so that the returned data changes according to the attribute in my component tag. So instead of `<grid-one />`, I can do `<grid-one type="posts" />`